# AWS Lambda called via Cloudfront in front of S3 bucket can't assume role for Cognito User Pool to authenticate

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-iam, aws-sts

I have an AWS Lambda that is run as a viewer request on a CloudFront instance that restricts access to an S3 bucket setup for static hosting of a website. It uses a Cognito User Pool to restrict access and verifies the credentials via `AdminInitiateAuth`.

The lambda runs fine using the test data directly obtained from logging the CloudFront event, however when actually called via the trigger from CloudFront I get the error:

```
An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the AdminInitiateAuth operation:
User: arn:aws:sts::<AWS_ACCOUNT_ID>:assumed-role/cloudfront_trigger_s3_auth_http_service/us-east-1.s3_service_resources_auth
is not authorized to perform: cognito-idp:AdminInitiateAuth on resource:
arn:aws:cognito-idp:us-west-2:<AWS_ACCOUNT_ID>:userpool/<USER_POOL_ID>
```

I've tried expanding my trust relationship and making sure that AWS STS can assume the role when it needs to.

`cloudfront_trigger_s3_auth_http_service` role trust relationship:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": [
          "cognito-idp.amazonaws.com",
          "edgelambda.amazonaws.com",
          "sts.amazonaws.com",
          "lambda.amazonaws.com"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

`arcimoto-service-resources-user-pool-auth` policy attached to `cloudfront_trigger_s3_auth_http_service` role that allows cognito access

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cognito-idp:AdminInitiateAuth",
                "sts:AssumeRole"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::511596272857:role/cloudfront_trigger_s3_auth_http_service/us-east-1.s3_service_resources_auth",
                "arn:aws:cognito-idp:us-east-1:511596272857:userpool/us-east-1_sES7sBpcg"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```